# Binding Flask AutoIndex to a different URL other than http://localhost?

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Flask and want to use the following basic example (using Flask-AutoIndex) in order to list files and folders in a directory:

```
import os.path
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.autoindex import AutoIndex

app = Flask(__name__)
AutoIndex(app, browse_root=os.path.curdir)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The example works fine for me,

```
http://localhost/folder1/folder2
```

is listing the files and folders in folder2.

The problem I have is that these urls are already bound to some other functions for other purposes, and this makes AutoIndex not working properly (URL conflicts)

Is it possible to bind AutoIndex to a different URL that has an extra word "list" in it? something like:

```
http://localhost/list/folder1/folder2/
http://localhost/list/folder1/folder2/folder3/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test it, but AutoIndex includes an AutoIndexBlueprint, so I wonder if you could use that to tuck it away:

```
# bp.py
from flask import Blueprint
from flask.ext.autoindex import AutoIndexBlueprint
auto_bp = Blueprint('auto_bp', __name__)
AutoIndexBlueprint(auto_bp, browse_root='/tmp')
```

Then register it on your app:

```
from bp import auto_bp
app.register_blueprint(auto_bp, url_prefix='/list')
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
files_index = AutoIndex(app, os.path.curdir + '/app/files', add_url_rules=False)
# Custom indexing
@app.route('/files')
@app.route('/files/<path:path>')
def autoindex(path='.'):
    return files_index.render_autoindex(path)
```

From https://github.com/sublee/flask-autoindex/issues/16